# TradingView : test against previous bar for input from an external indicator does not give results

Tags: pine-script

I have an indicator so calculate the sma of a stoch from another symbol

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="SPY_STRATEGY_W", shorttitle="SPY_STRATEGY_W", overlay=false, timeframe="1W")
TimeFrame = input.timeframe("1W")


[close_index, hi, lo] = request.security("index:S5FI",TimeFrame , [close, high, low],lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on, gaps=barmerge.gaps_on)

start_month = input(6)
start_year = input(2021)

length = input.int(5, minval=1)
smoothK = 3
k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(close_index, hi, lo, length), smoothK)

buydot2 = k > k[1]
selldot2 = k < k[1]
plotshape(buydot2,"buy",shape.circle, location.bottom , color=color.green)
plotshape(selldot2, "sell",  shape.circle, location.bottom, color=color.red)

h1l = hline(20)
h0h = hline(80) 

plot(k, title = "k", color=color.new(#bbd9fb, 0),style=plot.style_stepline)
```

this output I want to use in a strategy.
I want to generate buy/sell signals on a daily chart of SPY when k changes direction on a weekly basis

```
//@version=5
strategy(title="Slow Stochastic", shorttitle="SPY_STRATEGY", overlay=false, initial_capital = 5000, pyramiding = 0, default_qty_type ="percent_of_equity", default_qty_value = 100, commission_type = "%",commission_value = 1  )

newk = input.source(close, "other indicator") 

buydot2 = newk > newk[1] 
selldot2 = newk < newk[1] 
plotshape(buydot2,"buy",shape.circle, location.bottom , color=color.blue, show_last = 1)
plotshape(selldot2, "sell",  shape.circle, location.bottom, color=color.yellow)
plot(newk, "newk", color=color.fuchsia, style= plot.style_stepline)

param_weekly = input(1)
start_month = input(1)
start_year = input(2021)
end_month = input(12)
end_year = input(2021)
v2stoploss_input = input(100, title='Stop Loss %')/100
v2takeprofit_input = input(1000, title='Take Profit %')/100

v2stoploss_level = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - v2stoploss_input)
v2takeprofit_level = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + v2takeprofit_input)


h1l = hline(20)
h0h = hline(80) 


score1=0
if (param_weekly==1 and time>timestamp(start_year, start_month, 01, 09, 30) and time<timestamp(end_year, end_month, 01, 09, 30))
    if score1==0 
        if (ta.crossover(newk,20))
            score1 := 1
    score1exit=0
    if (ta.crossunder(newk,80))
        score1exit :=1                   
    if (score1 == 1) 
        strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    if (score1exit == 1)            
        strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
    strategy.exit("Stoploss/TP", "Long", stop = v2stoploss_level, limit = v2takeprofit_level)  

score2=0
score2exit=0
if (param_weekly==2 and time>timestamp(start_year, start_month, 01, 09, 30) and time<timestamp(end_year, end_month, 01, 09, 30))
    if score2==0 
        if newk[0] > newk[1]
            score2 := 1
    if score2exit==0
        if newk[0] < newk[1]
            score2exit :=1                   
    if (score2exit == 1) 
        strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    if (score2exit == 1)            
        strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
    strategy.exit("Stoploss/TP", "Long", stop = v2stoploss_level, limit = v2takeprofit_level)
```

I am testing, but no dots are shown on the chart. k_w is however correctly plotted, which is strange, because the values are present. but the value of the previous bar is lost ?

calling another security for a different timeframe in a strategy does not work

Comment: Can you edit your question and share your working code please ? The actual code doesn't plot anything and generates errors.

Comment: Edited and paste full code. tx !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Did you checked start/end dates in your strategy?
2. What is the idea of using `timeframe` parameter in the indicator and then request.security() function?

When you're requesting 1W data on the daily chart, you have only 1 value per week, so `buydot2` and `selldot2` conditions in strategy script always false:

```
buydot2 = newk > newk[1] 
selldot2 = newk < newk[1]
```

You can set gaps parameters to false, then you will have same value every 7 days.

```
indicator(title="SPY_STRATEGY_W", shorttitle="SPY_STRATEGY_W", overlay=false, timeframe="1W", timeframe_gaps = false)
```

but it is still strange way of calculating things.

3. ta.crossover(newk,20) should be put in global scope.
4. Initial capital might be too low.

I suggest you to using normal way and calculate data in the strategy script.

```
//@version=5
strategy(title="Slow Stochastic", shorttitle="SPY_STRATEGY", overlay=false, initial_capital = 5000, pyramiding = 0, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value = 100, commission_type = strategy.commission.percent, commission_value = 1 )

TimeFrame = input.timeframe("1W")
param_weekly = input(1)
start_month = input(1)
start_year = input(2021)
end_month = input(12)
end_year = input(2024)
v2stoploss_input = input(100, title='Stop Loss %')/100
v2takeprofit_input = input(1000, title='Take Profit %')/100
length = input.int(5, minval=1)
smoothK = 3

newk =  request.security("index:S5FI",TimeFrame , ta.sma(ta.stoch(close, high, low, length), smoothK))

buydot2 = newk > newk[1]
selldot2 = newk < newk[1]

h1l = hline(20)
h0h = hline(80) 
plotshape(buydot2,"buy",shape.circle, location.bottom , color=color.green)
plotshape(selldot2, "sell",  shape.circle, location.bottom, color=color.red)


v2stoploss_level = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - v2stoploss_input)
v2takeprofit_level = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + v2takeprofit_input)


cOver = ta.crossover(newk,20)
cUnder = ta.crossunder(newk,80)

score1=0
if (param_weekly==1 and time>timestamp(start_year, start_month, 01, 09, 30) and time<timestamp(end_year, end_month, 01, 09, 30))
    if score1==0  and cOver
        score1 := 1
    score1exit=0
    if cUnder
        score1exit :=1                   
    if (score1 == 1) 
        strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    if (score1exit == 1)            
        strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
    strategy.exit("Stoploss/TP", "Long", stop = v2stoploss_level, limit = v2takeprofit_level)  

score2=0
score2exit=0
if (param_weekly==2 and time>timestamp(start_year, start_month, 01, 09, 30) and time<timestamp(end_year, end_month, 01, 09, 30))
    if score2==0 
        if newk[0] > newk[1]
            score2 := 1
    if score2exit==0
        if newk[0] < newk[1]
            score2exit :=1                   
    if (score2exit == 1) 
        strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    if (score2exit == 1)            
        strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
    strategy.exit("Stoploss/TP", "Long", stop = v2stoploss_level, limit = v2takeprofit_level)
```